# Variational Autoencoder (VAE) Shows Inconsistent Output

Tags: python, machine-learning, neural-network, keras, autoencoder

On the basis of [this example](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/master/examples/variational_autoencoder.py) in keras, I've build an autoencoder and trained it on the MNIST dataset, but depending on *how* I reconstruct the input, the output is different.

Row 1 = the original MNIST `test_data`

Row 2 = `decoder(encoder(test_data))`

Row 3 = `full_vae_model(test_data)`

[image: MNIST digits]

If you look close, you'll see that the digits in row 2 and 3 look different. Can someone explain why this is the case? To my understanding, it shouldn't make any difference by which of the two paths I reconstruct the original data.

Here's the structure of a variational autoencoder (image taken from [this article](https://towardsdatascience.com/intuitively-understanding-variational-autoencoders-1bfe67eb5daf)). Now when I take the input and pass it thorugh the whole network, why isn't it the same as passing it through to the latent vector, and then this intermediate result again through to the output? What happens in between?

[image: VAE structure]

Here is the code, slightly modified from the [keras example](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/master/examples/variational_autoencoder.py) (but no changes made in the architecture)

```
'''Example of VAE on MNIST dataset using MLP
The VAE has a modular design. The encoder, decoder and VAE
are 3 models that share weights. After training the VAE model,
the encoder can be used to  generate latent vectors.
The decoder can be used to generate MNIST digits by sampling the
latent vector from a Gaussian distribution with mean=0 and std=1.
# Reference
[1] Kingma, Diederik P., and Max Welling.
"Auto-encoding variational bayes."
https://arxiv.org/abs/1312.6114
'''

from __future__ import absolute_import
from __future__ import division
from __future__ import print_function

from keras.layers import Lambda, Input, Dense
from keras.models import Model
from keras.datasets import mnist
from keras.losses import mse, binary_crossentropy
from keras.utils import plot_model
from keras import backend as K

import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import os


# reparameterization trick
# instead of sampling from Q(z|X), sample eps = N(0,I)
# z = z_mean + sqrt(var)*eps
def sampling(args):
    """Reparameterization trick by sampling fr an isotropic unit Gaussian.
    # Arguments:
        args (tensor): mean and log of variance of Q(z|X)
    # Returns:
        z (tensor): sampled latent vector
    """

    z_mean, z_log_var = args
    batch = K.shape(z_mean)[0]
    dim = K.int_shape(z_mean)[1]
    # by default, random_normal has mean=0 and std=1.0
    epsilon = K.random_normal(shape=(batch, dim))
    return z_mean + K.exp(0.5 * z_log_var) * epsilon

# MNIST dataset
(x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = mnist.load_data()

image_size = x_train.shape[1]
original_dim = image_size * image_size
x_train = np.reshape(x_train, [-1, original_dim])
x_test = np.reshape(x_test, [-1, original_dim])
x_train = x_train.astype('float32') / 255
x_test = x_test.astype('float32') / 255

# network parameters
input_shape = (original_dim, )
intermediate_dim = 512
batch_size = 128
latent_dim = 32
epochs = 50

# VAE model = encoder + decoder
# build encoder model
inputs = Input(shape=input_shape, name='encoder_input')
x = Dense(intermediate_dim, activation='relu')(inputs)
z_mean = Dense(latent_dim, name='z_mean')(x)
z_log_var = Dense(latent_dim, name='z_log_var')(x)

# use reparameterization trick to push the sampling out as input
# note that "output_shape" isn't necessary with the TensorFlow backend
z = Lambda(sampling, output_shape=(latent_dim,), name='z')([z_mean, z_log_var])

# instantiate encoder model
encoder = Model(inputs, [z_mean, z_log_var, z], name='encoder')
encoder.summary()
#plot_model(encoder, to_file='vae_mlp_encoder.png', show_shapes=True)

# build decoder model
latent_inputs = Input(shape=(latent_dim,), name='z_sampling')
x = Dense(intermediate_dim, activation='relu')(latent_inputs)
outputs = Dense(original_dim, activation='sigmoid')(x)

# instantiate decoder model
decoder = Model(latent_inputs, outputs, name='decoder')
decoder.summary()
#plot_model(decoder, to_file='vae_mlp_decoder.png', show_shapes=True)

# instantiate VAE model
outputs = decoder(encoder(inputs)[2])
vae = Model(inputs, outputs, name='vae_mlp')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    models = (encoder, decoder)
    data = (x_test, y_test)

    # VAE loss = mse_loss or xent_loss + kl_loss
    #reconstruction_loss = mse(inputs, outputs)
    reconstruction_loss = binary_crossentropy(inputs, outputs)

    reconstruction_loss *= original_dim
    kl_loss = 1 + z_log_var - K.square(z_mean) - K.exp(z_log_var)
    kl_loss = K.sum(kl_loss, axis=-1)
    kl_loss *= -0.5
    vae_loss = K.mean(reconstruction_loss + kl_loss)
    vae.add_loss(vae_loss)
    vae.compile(optimizer='adam')
    vae.summary()

    # train the autoencoder
    vae.fit(x_train,
            epochs=epochs,
            batch_size=batch_size,
            validation_data=(x_test, None))
    #vae.save_weights('vae_mlp_mnist.h5')

    z_mean, z_log_var, z = encoder.predict(x_test)
    decoded_imgs = decoder.predict(z_mean)
    Y_img = vae.predict(x_test)

    n = 10  # how many digits we will display
    plt.figure(figsize=(20, 4))
    for i in range(n):
        # display original
        ax = plt.subplot(3, n, i + 1)
        plt.imshow(x_test[i].reshape(28, 28))
        plt.gray()
        ax.get_xaxis().set_visible(False)
        ax.get_yaxis().set_visible(False)

        # display reconstruction
        ax = plt.subplot(3, n, i + 1 + n)
        plt.imshow(decoded_imgs[i].reshape(28, 28))
        plt.gray()
        ax.get_xaxis().set_visible(False)
        ax.get_yaxis().set_visible(False)

        # display reconstruction 2
        ax = plt.subplot(3, n, i + 1 + 2 * n)
        plt.imshow(Y_img[i].reshape(28, 28))
        plt.gray()
        ax.get_xaxis().set_visible(False)
        ax.get_yaxis().set_visible(False)
    plt.show()
```

Answer (score 3):

I think if you even run `decoder(encoder(test_data))` twice with the same `test_data`, you should get different output and that is the correct behavior.

If you can refer to "Tutorial on Variational Autoencoders", see Figure 4 (right) which is about "A training-time variational autoencoder implemented as a feed-forward neural network". It is sampling epsilon from the normal distribution so epsilon is a random variable and its realization is different whenever you call the function in your code.